DBT commands are not working in AWS MWAA 2.9.2
Due to project security concerns, we were asked to upgrade the airflow version from 2.0.2 to 2.9.2 in AWS MWAA
However while upgrading to 2.9.2, we are facing severe concerns and not even a single DBT command is working, I've created a simple DAG as in below:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

from airflow_dbt.operators.dbt_operator import (
    DbtRunOperator,
    DbtTestOperator
)
import os 
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime
import uuid

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Paris")

DBT_FOLDER = 'Project/transformation/dbt'
DBT_BIN = '/usr/local/airflow/.local/bin/dbt'
DBT_PROJECT_DIR = f'/usr/local/airflow/dags/{DBT_FOLDER}/'
DBT_PROFILES_DIR = f'/usr/local/airflow/dags/{DBT_FOLDER}/'

ENV = os.environ.get("AIRFLOW__ENVIRONMENT")

ACCOUNT = ****
DATABASE = ****
ROLE = ****
WAREHOUSE = ****
USER = os.getenv('AIRFLOW__SECRET_VAR_SNOWFLAKE_USER')
PASSWORD = os.getenv('AIRFLOW__SECRET_VAR_SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD')

if ENV.lower() == 'dev':
    DBT_TARGET = 'dev_live'
elif ENV.lower() == 'uat':
    DBT_TARGET = 'uat_live'
elif ENV.lower() == 'prod':
    DBT_TARGET = 'prod_live'
else:
    DBT_TARGET = ''

def print_hello():
    print("Hello from Airflow!")

def print_end():
    print("Hello from Airflow!- Ending")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Project',
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 3, 9, 0, 15, tzinfo=local_tz),
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'Project_TRY',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Project Try',
    # schedule_interval='10 */2 * * *',
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
)

with dag:
    start_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='print_hello_task',
        python_callable=print_hello,
    )

    try_dbtcommand = BashOperator(
        task_id='try_dbtcommand',
        bash_command=f"{DBT_BIN} run --project-dir {DBT_PROJECT_DIR} --profiles-dir {DBT_PROFILES_DIR} --target {DBT_TARGET} --select model_try"
    )
    end_task=PythonOperator(
        task_id='print_end_task',
        python_callable=print_end,
    )

start_task  >>  try_dbtcommand >> end_task

I'm using the following requirements:
apache-airflow==2.9.2
airflow-dbt==0.4.0
boto3==1.34.106
dbt-snowflake==1.5.4
sqlfluff==2.3.5
sqlfluff-templater-dbt==2.3.5

constraints.txt
Both the above Python functions in the DAG are working but not the DBT command.
I've tried it locally running the DBT command and is working perfect however when we pushed into AWS 2.9.2 MWAA. We are facing the issues.
I tried using DBTTestOperator, DBTRunOperator but the same scenario repeated and there's no proper error statement in the error log, which is not helping me to proceed further.

Have you tried with the mwaa local runner?

@SimonP No i haven’t tried the mwaa local runner as we have the dependency with git & aws for pulling the credentials. however i just tried running the dbt command and is working locally. Could you please help me how can i run it locally.

https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner

setup the local runner using the requirements you posted above.

test using the dbt --version command

Hi, I'm not able to install the above requirements in the local runner due to dependency conflicts.  Can you confirm DBT is installed by running pip freeze with bash operator

https://astronomer.github.io/astronomer-cosmos/getting_started/mwaa.html alternative is to use cosmos

@SimonP https://github.com/sritar99/dbt_practise/blob/main/constraints.txt please use the constraints file from the following path.
Please try this and let me know if any issues
Thanks for sharing the alternative, i'll try cosmos in parllel

HI, using the local runner, the DBT commands work,
[2024-09-24, 18:37:03 UTC] {{subprocess.py:75}} INFO - Running command: ['/usr/bin/bash', '-c', '/usr/local/***/.local/bin/dbt --version']
[2024-09-24, 18:37:03 UTC] {{subprocess.py:86}} INFO - Output:
[2024-09-24, 18:37:06 UTC] {{subprocess.py:93}} INFO - Core:
[2024-09-24, 18:37:06 UTC] {{subprocess.py:93}} INFO -   - installed: 1.5.11
[2024-09-24, 18:37:06 UTC] {{subprocess.py:93}} INFO -   - latest:    1.8.6  - Update available!

I would look at the worker logs, and compare to the local runner log. On previous MWAA versions aws pinned watchtower after requirements are installed. check the installed lib on the worker with pip in a bash operator

@SimonP can we connect over a short call ? please share your email so that will contact you with more details.
reach out to me at sadhutarun00@gmail.com
